# Carousel bootstrap working on localhost but not on GitHub pages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Carousel bootstrap working on localhost but not on GitHub pages, other bootstrap styles are work properly.

while loading the site on this [URL](https://noamsachartov.github.io/AlexDesign/), the console says failed to upload 3 photos, and do not refer to the carousel problem. 
I have double-checked the bootstrap CDN but it is ok, also the `img path` is OK.

GitHub project - https://github.com/Noamsachartov/AlexDesign

URL: https://noamsachartov.github.io/AlexDesign/

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with Linux now and in Linux `filename` is case sensitive, so rename your `Proj1.jpg` to `proj1.jpg` and your problem will be solved.

Here is the line that creates a problem.

https://github.com/Noamsachartov/AlexDesign/blob/759c05c8de613d640cbba90ad343fdd329981fa6/index.html#L40